# SQL query with logic

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me with SQL query.

My table structure with data is:

[image: database]

How can select all rows without duplicates Event_ID?

And `Event_NAME` predominantly must contain **http://**

But if does not exist `Event_NAME` with **http://**, then `Event_NAME` must contain **Connect**

Finally selection result assumed

[image]

Syntax Oracle.

Thank all in advance for help.

Comment: What query have you used to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to select all rows with Event_NAME containing 'http://', and then select any events not in the first set that have 'Connect' in Event_NAME.

I'm assuming that the only possibilities are the ones you show above - either there's two entries (http and Connect) for an event, or there's just 'Connect' - though this query could work for other situations.

The query is a union between 1. all events with 'http://' in the Event_NAME, and 2. events that don't have an Event_ID in the first set and that have 'Connect' in their Event_NAME.

There are probably prettier ways to do this, but it works in Oracle with the test data:

```
SELECT * FROM eventtest WHERE Event_NAME LIKE 'http://%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM eventtest
WHERE Event_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT Event_ID FROM eventtest WHERE Event_NAME LIKE 'http://%');
```

Answer (score 2):

here are 2 approaches requiring only a single pass of the data:

```
SELECT
      Event_ID
    , MAX(Event_NAME) AS Event_NAME
FROM eventtest
GROUP BY
      Event_ID
;

SELECT
      ID
    , Event_ID
    , Event_NAME
FROM (
      SELECT
            ID
          , Event_ID
          , Event_NAME
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Event_ID ORDER BY Event_NAME DESC) AS rn
      FROM eventtest
      ) dt
WHERE rn = 1
;
```